# How to download images from s3 as numpy arrays?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am trying to train a neural network where I pass in a series of images. I want to create a generator which passes each image in as a numpy array

```
from skimage import io
image_array = io.imread(url)
```

I want something like this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('some-bucket')
def my_generator():
    for object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        image_array = io.imread(object)    # this will not work. object is of type s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='manga-learn-data', key=u'one-piece-colored-5340113_06_05.png') whereas io.imread is expecting a url or uri. 
        yield image_array
```

But that image_array variable will never work. Everything I can find about downloading images from amazon s3 indicates that you download the file to a file. I want to download it to an image object that I can open as an array.

Comment: Would you be comfortable with using the [built-in HTTP endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro) for your S3 files? Is the cost of saving a file and reading from it too expensive?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [docs for imread](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread), it appears that it only supports passing in a filename or a URL. So no file-like objects. So it looks like you have two options: save to a temp file, or [generate a presigned url](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) to pass in. Here's an example of generating that pre-signed url:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
params = {'Bucket': 'foo', 'Key': 'img.jpg'}
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object', Params=params)
```

Comment: Apparently `skimage.io.imread` does not accept long URLs. Once I got `url` as @Jordon Phillips does, I had to do:
from urllib.request import urlopen;
with urlopen(url) as conn:
    image = io.imread(conn)